# In AてBてもらう does もらう operate on A and B?

Tags: grammar, parsing, giving-and-receiving

[Regarding stickers put on apples to make pictures](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011686001000/k10011686001000.html):

> シールを作った会社が毎年、農家の人にお願いしてこのりんごを作ってもらっています。
>   Every year the company that makes these stickers receives requests from farmers and receives the apples they make.

I'm a bit confused about how to parse this sentence. Does もらう operate on both 作る **and** お願いする? I see two separate things here

> 1) 会社が毎年、農家の人にお願いしてもらっています。
>   Every year the company receives (the benefit of) requests from farmers.

This makes sense. The farmers want fancy pictures on their apples so they ask for stickers.

> 2) 会社が毎年、農家の人にこのりんごを作ってもらっています。
>   Every year the company receives (the benefit of) the farmers making these apples.

This makes no sense to me at all. Why would the farmers be making the apples **for** the sticker company?

I fear I have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does もらう operate on both 作る and お願いする?

もらう operates on 作る.

You can split the sentence this way:

1) 会社が毎年、農家の人にお願いしています。
Every year the company makes requests to farmers.

2) 会社が毎年、農家の人にこのりんごを作ってもらっています。
Every year the company receives (the benefit of) the farmers making these apples.

> シールを作った会社が毎年、農家の人にお願いしてこのりんごを作ってもらっています。
>   Every year the company that made these sticker makes a request / asks the farmers and has them make these apples.

---

> Why would the farmers be making the apples for the sticker company?

[ここによりますと](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20181025/k10011686001000.html):

> 「シールを開発した弘前市の農業資材メーカー『佐藤袋店』では、毎年、市内の生産農家に『絵入りりんご』の栽培を依頼し、総理大臣官邸のほか、... ベルサイユ宮殿などにも贈っています。」
>   「農業資材メーカーの佐藤義博社長は ...『無事に出荷できてうれしいです』と話していました。」

とありますので、会社が絵入りリンゴを仕入れて、出荷してるみたいですね。。

Comment: Would you say that 農家の人に is also **explicitly** part of the second clause so the に particle has changed meaning between the first and second clauses ('to' in the first and  'from' in the second)? Or would you say that 農家の人に is not a part of the second clause, and it is just implied? The idea that you can use the same particle (に) with two different meanings is a bit too spooky.

Comment: @user3856370 I think it's the latter. (`農家の人に is not a part of the second clause, and it is just implied`). なぜかというと、例えば・・・「彼女**を**連れてきた + 彼女**に**掃除させた」→「彼女**を**連れてきて掃除させた。」(彼女を is not a part of the second clause, and 彼女に is implied), 「鈴木さん**に**毒を飲ませた + 鈴木さん**を**殺した。」→「鈴木さん**に**毒を飲ませて殺した。」(鈴木さんに is not a part of the second clause, and 鈴木さんを is implied).